# Can I set the value of a circleci parameter as part of the run?

Tags: circleci

I'm upgrading to CircleCI version 2.1

```
version: 2.1
```

I would like to declare a parameter, but give it a value during the run.

The reason for this is to utilize the `when` clause.

This would look something like:

```
parameters:   my-param:
    type: string
    default: ""

jobs:   
  build:
    steps:
    - checkout
    - run:
        name: Set the param
        command: << parameters.my-param >> = my-value
```

The reason for this is I do not know the value until I run a command on the commit that triggered the build.  I did something similar in 2.0, so that I could skip certain jobs based on the input, but I've run into limitations of 2.1.

Is this possible?

Any ideas for a workaround that achieve what I'm trying to do would be greatly appreciated!